# Querying graphql from Ionic via Native Http

Tags: ionic-framework, graphql, ionic-native, ionic-native-http

I'm migrating some services from Rest to Graphql in an Ionic App. I use the Ionic/Cordova native http plugin in order to make requests to my server, in the following way:

```
import {HTTP} from '@ionic-native/http/ngx'

@Injectable()
export class ApiProvider {

  private server = "https://api.myserver.com/'

   constructor(
   private nativeHttp:HTTP 
  )
   {}
 
    getData(path:string,params = "")
    {
        const url = this.server + path + params
        return this.nativeHttp.get(url,{},{
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        })
    }
}
```

My question is: How can I pass a graphql query in it? I've tried making the full url look like this `https://api.myserver.com/graphql?query={people{id,name}}` but I got the following error from graphql:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Unknown operation named \"IntrospectionQuery\"."
    }
  ]
}
```

which differs from the successful result that I get in Postman for the exact same url.

How can I make this query using the http plugin?

Thank you in beforehand!

Comment: https://www.javascripttuts.com/implementing-graphql-using-apollo-in-an-ionic-application-introduction/

another link 
https://github.com/aaronksaunders/ionic4-angular6-gql/blob/master/README.md

Comment: why would you do this where there is an excellent graphql api to handle this for you?